# aws devicefarm python upload apk - android_app_aapt_debug_badging_failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-device-farm

I am uploading the APK using python code, when I check for status after create_upload and uploading the actual file then I keep getting FAILED with android_app_aapt_debug_badging_failed. Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear that you are running into issues with the upload.
For the error code you are facing, i am pasting the debugging steps below

Debugging Steps
During the upload validation process, AWS Device Farm parses out information from the output of an "aapt debug badging " command.

Make sure that you can run this command on your Android application successfully. In the following example, the package's name is app-debug.apk.

Copy your application package to your working directory, and then run the command:

$ aapt debug badging app-debug.apk
A valid Android application package should produce output like the following:

package: name='com.amazon.aws.adf.android.referenceapp' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0' platformBuildVersionName='5.1.1-1819727'
sdkVersion:'9'
application-label:'ReferenceApp'
application: label='ReferenceApp' icon='res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-debuggable
launchable-activity: name='com.amazon.aws.adf.android.referenceapp.Activities.MainActivity' label='ReferenceApp' icon=''
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.bluetooth'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.bluetooth' reason='requested android.permission.BLUETOOTH permission, and targetSdkVersion > 4'
main
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '160' '213' '240' '320' '480' '640'

Comment: It turned out that the upload was bad, python code was not reading the full file.

Comment: @Sam I'm running into the same issue here. Can you let me know how did you upload the file? Did you use Requests or PyCurl?

Comment: I was missing content-length header I was using requests I believe. I think you should use fastlane's plugin tho.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue, and none of the suggestions were doing any good.

The fix was to assign the file to `data` instead of `files`.

```
def upload_app(path):
    url, arn = create_signed_upload('ANDROID_APP')
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
    with open(path, 'rb') as app:
        requests.put(url, data=app, headers=headers)
    success = wait_on_upload(arn)
    return success
```